# Обработка полученного массива строк в результате выполнения какой-либо команды в Powershell

Tags: массивы, строки, powershell

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Poweshell "по-человечески" обработать массив строк, который получается в результате вывода некоторой внешней команды. Здесь и на других сайтах можно найти полно примеров, как преобразовать массив объектов в массив строк. А вот выполнить обратную операцию?
Например, внешний exe-шник дает такой вывод, нужно по имени определить uuid:

```
uuid        : 111-111-111
name        : name1
description : description1

uuid        : 222-222-222
name        : name2
description : 
...
uuid        : 123-123-123
name        : name21
description : description21
...
```

Решение в лоб:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $exe_result.Count; $i++ ) {
if ($exe_result[$i].endswith("искомое имя")) { $exe_result[$i-1]} }
```

Но такой метод подходит только для данного набора параметров, когда мы точно знаем, что за uuid идет name и ищем только по одному параметру. Как сделать процедуру выборки более универсальной? Преобразовать в массив объектов, двумерный массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если мы знаем, что у нас определённый набор полей, который повторяется и не меняется, то можем построить из строковых данных HashTable по нужным параметрам. Из HashTable можем построить PSObject и с ним уже работать.

Как черновой вариант (родился за 2 минуты, возможно есть и более оптимальные алгоритмы).

1. Пусть вывод программы идёт в переменную для удобства:

   ```
   $data = "
   uuid        : 111-111-111
   name        : name1
   description : description1

   uuid        : 222-222-222
   name        : name2
   description : 
   ...
   uuid        : 123-123-123
   name        : name21
   description : description21
   ...
   "
   ```
2. Теперь распарсим получившиеся строки в HashTable (ищем конкретные параметры в массиве строк):

   ```
   $hashtable = @{
       UUID = @(([regex]::Matches($data, 'uuid.+')).value -replace 'uuid\s+:\s(.+)','$1')
       names = @(([regex]::Matches($data, 'name.+')).value -replace 'name\s+:\s(.+)','$1')
       descr = @(([regex]::Matches($data, 'description.+')).value -replace 'description\s+:\s(.+)','$1')
   }
   ```
3. Посчитаем количество значений HashTable и засунем по отдельности в PSObject:

   ```
   $obj = 1..$hashtable.UUID.Count | ForEach-Object {
       New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
           UUID = $hashtable.UUID[$_ - 1]
           Name = $hashtable.names[$_ - 1]
           Description = $hashtable.descr[$_ - 1]
       }
   }
   ```

Получаем на выходе стандартный PSObject, с которого уже можем спрашивать, например, по name:

```
PS C:\> $obj | Where-Object {$_.name -eq 'name2'}

UUID        Description Name 
----        ----------- ---- 
222-222-222             name2
```